# htaccess pretty URL rewrites break in sub-folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the code below which works a charm when the site is placed in the web root:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
 RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

However unfortunately the site I've been working on is a microsite which won't live in the web root. Instead it will live in a URL such as /custom/test/  - now when the URLs are rewritten this part of the URL is removed.

The htaccess file needs to sit within this sub folder so that the rest of the site isn't effected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rewrite base and remove the leading slash from the redirect rule (or add the base there as well):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /custom/test/

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
 RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1/ [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

These rules would need to be in an htaccess file in your `/custom/test/` directory.

Comment: Thanks - I did try that and it didn't seem to work - I've now replaced all .php extensions in any links on the site with a / and this seems to now work - so it was just swapping out the .php for the slash that was breaking - otherwise the rest of the rewrite seems to work.